# attempting to modify a field in codeigniter application db table but know how to identify the table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am beginner in code igniter php framework. Today I have a task to modify existing code and somehow I am lost in the middle of the line on attempting to located a database table. This is the controller snippet that renders the view

```
..........
$data["all_types"] = $this->data_model->get_data("all_types",300,"Asc");
$this->load->view("preview_brands",$data);
...........
```

when the view is loaded I am iterating through the in the view to load data as shown

```
 <div class="decoration"></div>
 <?php foreach($all_types as $item): ?>
 <div style="display:block;color:#000;">
    <a style="font-size:17px;margin:15px 2px;font-family:Cgothic;"
                           href="<?php echo site_url()."...../..../".$item["id"]; ?>"
                           class="scale-hover"
                           title="<?php echo str_replace("_"," ",$item["name"]);?>">
    <strong><?php echo str_replace("_"," ",$item["name"]);?></strong>
    </a>

 </div>             
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

this is the model snippet code as shown

```
function get_data($db,$i,$order)
{
   $this->db->order_by("name",$order);
   $this->db->where('consent',"yes");
   $query=$this->db->get($db);
   return $query->result_array();
}
```

My challenge is how can I locate or identify the database table the above model is pointing to to fetch data. Hoping someone assists me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**all_types** is your table name.

$this->db->get($your_table name), get method take table name as a parameter.

[Get Method Documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=get#CI_DB_query_builder::get)

If more help needed I'm happy to help.

**Happy Coding**.

Answer (score 0):

From your model code:

```
$query=$this->db->get($db);
```

This means `$db` is the table name. Looking at your controller code which calls the model function:

```
$data["all_types"] = $this->data_model->get_data("all_types",300,"Asc");
```

I can say that **all_types** is the name of the table.